# How to compule equations like <math>...</math>

Tags: equations, pdftex

Good afternoon ,

My question is very simple even though I don't know if it's relevant .

How can I compile equations like this ( that I copied from wikipedia ) in latex :

```
<math>dissim(C_1,C_2) = \max_{x\in C_1, y\in C_2}(dissim(x,y))</math>
```

Thank you for help !

Comment: What's `dissim`?

Comment: It's means dissimilarity between two objects ( just like any user defined function / it's a latex user text  )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have tex installed save a file such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\operatorname{dissim}(C_1,C_2) = \max_{x\in C_1, y\in C_2}(\operatorname{dissim}(x,y))\]

\end{document}
```

Run `pdflatex file` and it will produce a `file.pdf` that looks like

[image]

If you don't have tex installed you can use an online tex such as Overleaf you could copy the project

https://www.overleaf.com/read/mnvvbvhjtbns

That has the above document.

You might also benefit from a tutorial such as https://learnlatex.org

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. This means that wikipedia uses Latex implicitely but there is no direct way to get the code ( They use an extension of MathJax if i understood ).

Comment: @TouMou  They use mathjax which is javascript and doesn't use tex at all. If your question was "how to I enable mathjax on my website" then that's off topic here you coudl ask at stackoverflow mathjax tag, or see the examples at mathjax.org

Comment: @TouMou the code you showed _is_ the code for mathjax, it does not use LaTeX and does not need the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` etc that I added for latex. If your web page loads the mathjax javascript and configures it to use `<math>` elements then you just need to add the text from your question in to the web page

Comment: I'm working in a pdf report not a website. There are some websites when i can copy the Latex code by a right click ( in the equation picture ) ---> options . I'm using the Mathpix free trial for this purpose

Comment: @TouMou I still don't understand your question the code you copied is the latex code, I changed `dissim` to `\operatorname{dissim}` but that was an urelated improvement (it would have improived the mathjax original to have that too) so you can in general simply copy the tex code from wikipedia and add it to a tex document.

Comment: I was seraching a way to copy wikipedia equations as Latex code , Mathpix do the job ( that's all ! ) . In wikipedia , I clicked on modify the code (an hypertext link) then i obtained the mathjax code . Based on your explanations , the pb is solved !

Comment: Thank you again sir for your valuable help !